# php - open href like page to specific position

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'd like to know if it's possible to open a page (`id=26`) at a specific position: .

At the front page i'm using this code at the php file to make the title link to the page

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(26); ?>">
    <?php if(!empty( $clean_biz_home_service_title ) ){ ?> 
    <h2>
        <?php echo esc_html(  $clean_biz_home_service_title); ?>
    </h2>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the content of that page (id=26), you need to add an id attribute to some tag, like so:

```
<div id="myposition">
...
</div>
```

Next, append `#myposition` after the `get_page_link(26)` call:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link(26); ?>#myposition">
    <?php if(!empty( $clean_biz_home_service_title ) ){ ?> 
    <h2>
        <?php echo esc_html(  $clean_biz_home_service_title); ?>
    </h2>
</a>
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use DOM selectors such as #maincontent. You would need to assign an ID to a section on the page and then append it to the trigger URL.

For ex: http://yourdomain.com/index.html#maincontent would take you to that div on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div name="position">
  content
</div>

<a href="asdf/1.php?id=1#position">link</a>
```

example:

if you click the link below you will open this page at #new-answer position

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597896/php-open-href-like-page-to-specific-position#new-answer)